# i want to count the number of returned rows from azure table

Tags: android, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I want to count the number of returned strings from azure table. so i found the following code and i tried to apply it. the code:

```
final MobileServiceList<Crime> result = mToDoTable.includeInlineCount().execute().get();
int count = result.getTotalCount();
```

when i apply the code it gives me an error. may you help me, what should i put to replace Crime.

Comment: what's the error content?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
int count = mToDoTable.execute().get().getTotalCount();
```

this will definitely give you your required answer.

Comment: can you tell me how i can use it in the code, thank you

Comment: i have tried to use it in different ways, but i did not work